# Yet another matchstick puzzle: 14 = 5

Tags: lateral-thinking, matches

Is the expression below correct?  No.  But I never take no for an answer.

[image]

Your task is to make the expression *true* by moving exactly **two** matchsticks.

As usual, inequalities are not allowed.  So is removing, burning, breaking, eating, etc. matches.

Hint:

> I never take no for an answer.

Comment: *spits out match* Sorry, I just read the last line.

Comment: The intended answer is out.  Someone voted to close the post.  I agree that the number of valid solution is too high to make this a good question for this site.  I hope you enjoyed it anyway.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

as you said

> I never take no for an answer.

> take this YES :)
>
>  [image]

Comment: This can also be read as "4 (is an element of) 5", which is true in many set-theoretic constructions of the natural numbers, such as the von Neumann ordinals: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers

Answer (score 48):

> this is how iranian people write numbers :
>  [image]

so

> [image]

Answer (score 42):

Could it be

> [image]

> where the left-hand side is not to be viewed as hundred eleven but instead three in roman numerals.

Comment: I first thought of making the 14 a "VI" and moving the bottom of the 5 to make it a weird 6, but this one's better

Comment: Username checks out.

Answer (score 41):

We all have our preferences for how numbers in writing look, right? :)

> [image]
>
>  9 = 9

Comment: Very clever approach :)

Comment: Yes, this is the same solution I saw within seconds.

Answer (score 26):

This is my sixth attempt, but I think this one might actually be the intended solution:

> [image]
>
>  Interpret as 11 base 4 = 5.

Answer (score 13):

A little far-fetched:

> [image: solution1]
>
>  Interpret as 1-1=0.

Even more far-fetched:

> [image: solution2]
>
>  Interpret as 7-1=6.

More fair, but actually not:

> Take a mirror and look at the image:
>  [image: presolution3]
>
>  Now an obvious and completely legal solution is:
>  [image: solution3]

Just... something:

> Flip the image upside down:
>  [image: presolution4]
>
>  And here goes the 'something':
>  [image: solution4]
>
>  hi = hi :)

Okay here's **a little** better one:

> [image: solution5]
>
>  Interpret as 10 = 10.

Comment: Your best solution would by your #4 upside down.

Answer (score 10):

We can move matches making up the 1 to get

> [image: 4 ∈ 5]
>  i.e. 4 ∈ 5. The standard definition of five (von Neumann ordinals) is
>  5 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, so this is in fact true.

Answer (score 8):

This could be very simple if you know Chinese numbers

[image]

so

> 4 = Si   Move the 2 matches from 1 to make SI or Si on the right side

And Si also means YES in Spanish.

Comment: The combination of Chinese and Spanish made the answer interesting!

Comment: The best answer!

Comment: Can you add a picture ? It is not obvious to me how you plan to place the matchsticks on the right hand side...

Comment: The idea is to write "SI", not the chinese character.

Answer (score 8):

take the leftmost pair and place them at far right a la "- |"

so it reads "4 = 5 - 1"

Comment: Could you include an image? You can download the image from the OP and edit it.

Answer (score 8):

Sorry about the bad quality of my image, I was using MS Paint...

> We're converting decimal to hex so `14 = E`  (I know we had to move two matches so I moved one of the `=` ones down a bit... It's still `=` !

> [image]

Comment: I like your second move :D

Answer (score 6):

Now that the hint is there,

> "[Never take no for an answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Never_Take_No_for_an_Answer)" is a 1951 movie.

And therefore the answer might be:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

If we

> Interpret `true` as a programmer might

We get

> [image]

This is valid because

> 14 + 5 evaluates to 19, which is non-zero, and so it is truthy

Answer (score 0):

I know you already have the answer, but I really wanted to solve this, so here is my solution :P

> [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, though, 'inequalities are not allowed'. Top marks for enthusiasm, but do make sure you read the question in full :)

Comment: Oh noos! I missed that :P I was so happy with it too ;)